# How to use TRIM in an extension?

Tags: api, internet-explorer, cross-browser, trim, crossrider

I come from a VB background and am trying to use trim in my extension. I tried using the following code but it doesn't work in IE7. How can I make it work?

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  ..
  var fieldText = $('#input').val().trim; // This line produces an error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The trim function is not supported in IE7 (support for trim started in IE9, see [compatibility details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)). However, you can use an Crossrider [appAPI.utils.trim](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.utils-method-trim) method that does the same thing and works on all browsers. So using your example, your code would be:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  ..
  var fieldText = appAPI.utils.trim($('#input').val()); // This line produces an error
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]